# Laravel 5.3 Log Permissions - Creating/Writing as nobody : nogroup

Tags: laravel, server-administration, laravel-upgrade

I'm in the middle of a Laravel upgrade from 5.2 to 5.3. I've been trying to find information regarding log permissions in the Laravel upgrade guide, but nothing has described the behavior I'm seeing.

After running `composer update`, for some reason the log files Laravel is generating are being set to 644 by default, under the `nobody` username and `nogroup` group.

This is causing issues when reverting back and forth between Laravel versions, as my 5.2 installation is not able to write to them, and consequently breaks the site.

One thing to keep in mind is I do not have sudo access on the server I'm working on, and the Laravel installation is in my `/home/$USER/` directory.

For now I've just been manually deleting the logs each time I have to revert/switch branches, but I am completely stumped on why Laravel is doing this.

What causes Laravel (and or other web apps) to act on files as the `nobody` user versus the user executing the code.

Does this have anything to do with `composer` updating dependencies and potentially their permissions/owner?

Comment: Why don't you just add the logfile to a .gitignore File?

Comment: This isn't a Git issue, the logs are already on a .gitignore. This has to do with why Laravel is creating files as the `nobody` user vs. the user that installed Laravel like it did in 5.2.